# Force specific __init__ execution with multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I'm trying to get the order of `__init__` executions right. The hierarchy consists of two branches. The left branch implements some abstract methods of the right branch. In the right branch there is also a split. Now I'd like them to execute: left first top to bottom, and then right top to bottom.

Is there a way to achieve that in Python 3?

So basically the following should print the numbers in order (which it doesn't):

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class L1:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(1)

class R1(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(3)

    @abstractmethod
    def m(self):
        pass

class L2(L1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(2)

    def m(self):
        pass

class R2a(R1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(4)

class R2b(R1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(4)

class X(L2, R2a):
    pass

class Y(L2, R2b):
    pass

x = X()
print("--")
y = Y()
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the order of L2 and R2 since L2 implements abstract methods of R2 (there will be errors if I change that).

Is it possible?

(Do you know a good way to think about MRO to solve such kind of problem easy?)

EDIT: I thought I doesn't matter, but I want to note that in my real structure, there is actually a diamond on the L side like L2a(L1), L2b(L1) and L2(L1a, L2a). That's to completely split some functionality.

Comment: You should derive you top level classes from `object`: `class L1 (object):` in order to get "new style classes".

Comment: @Ber, no, he's using Python 3 (otherwise the metaclass syntax wouldn't work) so he doesn't have to inherit explicitly from `object`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class L1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init()
        super().__init__()
    def init(self):
        print(1)

class R1(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        print(3)
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def m(self):
        pass

class L2(L1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        print(2)

    def m(self):
        pass

class R2a(R1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(4)


class R2b(R1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(4)

class X(L2, R2a):
    pass

class Y(L2, R2b):
    pass

x = X()
print([cls.__name__ for cls in X.mro()])
```

which yields

```
1
2
3
4
['X', 'L2', 'L1', 'R2a', 'R1', 'object']
```

I don't think you can change the MRO, `['X', 'L2', 'L1', 'R2a', 'R1', 'object']`. But you can choose to place initialization statements before or after `super().__init__()`.

Placing the print statements before `super().__init__()` gives you the print statements in the order of the MRO. Placing them afterwards, reverses the order.

You want the order partially reversed: L1 before L2, R1 before R2a.

When we reach L1, by calling `self.init()`, we get to start over at the beginning of the MRO chain, and call `init` in the desired order: `L1, L2`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to avoid the use of super:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init A')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init B')

class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print('init C')

c = C()
```

This prints:

```
init A
init B
init C
```

So for your specific situation just call _*init*_in whatever order you want. Really. just try it. Diamond or no diamond it will work out fine.

EG:

```
class X(L2,R2a):
    def __init__(self):
        L1.__init__(self)
        L2.__init__(self)
        R1.__init__(self)
        R2a.__init__(self)
```

If you need to call **init** for stuff higher up in the hierarchy and you are afraid of calling certain class's **init** functions repeatedly for certain objects then just make some boolean flags.

For example:

```
class L1:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            if self.l1_initialised:
                return
        except NameError:
            self.l1_initialised = True
        blah blah blah
```

Comment: But the problem is diamond structures, where superclass would be called twice. I actually didnt mention that my L2 class also has a splitting.

Comment: @Sheena: you should use super() to make hte method resolution order (MRO) algorithm work. http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: @Ber: thanks. looking into it... I've never had a problem with this way of doing things before though